# New index progress indication

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

When indexing on a cluster, the database status page in the admin consoles starts failing. I'm indexing a timestamp on indexing priority 2 in a billion documents and this may take a week or two.

What is the best way to get an idea about the indexing progress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Management API's [GET /manage/v2/databases/{id|name}?view=status](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]@view=status) page. You'll send an HTTP request, such as:

http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/Documents?view=status

to check out the Documents database on localhost. One part of the information retrieved will be reindexing status.